Assigning multiple values received via ZMQ to nodes?
I'm trying to take data streamed over LSL into Blender to dynamically update my animation. I've succeeded in my LSL processing, and streaming using ZMQ. When I connect to the socket using the GUI button in Blender, it's clearly getting connected:

but it's not updating dynamically with new data, like this tutorial shows.
And finally, I think I'm having issues decoding the dictionary to alter the parameters of interest. Over a few days I've cooked this script up with ClaudeAI and it's clearly trying to work, all the keyframes appear and it slightly buffers when I hit "run" but I don't think the numbers in the dictionary I'm sending over are getting picked out right.
import bpy
import zmq
import json
import threading

# Define the object and nodes
aurora = bpy.data.objects.get('Aurora')
material = aurora.active_material
geo = bpy.data.node_groups['Geometry Nodes']
hueNode = material.node_tree.nodes[8]
brightNode = material.node_tree.nodes[3]
wiggleNode = geo.nodes[19]

# Normalize input number across the purpley color range
def colourRange(valA, lA, hA):
    valA = max(min(valA, hA), lA)
    facA = (valA - lA) / (hA - lA)
    return 0.68 + facA * (0.9 - 0.68)

# Normalize Emission node brightness
def brightRange(valB, lB, hB):
    valB = max(min(valB, hB), lB)
    facB = (valB - lB) / (hB - lB)
    return 11 + facB * (17 - 11)

# Make it wiggle a bizzle
def wiggleRange(valC, lC, hC):
    valC = max(min(valC, hC), lC)
    facC = (valC - lC) / (hC - lC)
    return 0.3 + facC * (1.2 - 0.3)

class DataManager:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = None
        self.lock = threading.Lock()

    def update_data(self, new_data):
        with self.lock:
            self.data = new_data

    def get_data(self):
        with self.lock:
            return self.data

data_manager = DataManager()

def receive_data():
    context = zmq.Context()
    socket = context.socket(zmq.SUB)
    socket.connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:12346")  # Connect to the publisher
    socket.setsockopt_string(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, 'eeg_audio')  # Subscribe to 'eeg_audio' topic

    while True:
        try:
            topic, message = socket.recv_multipart()
            data = json.loads(message.decode('utf-8'))
            data_manager.update_data(data)
            print(f"Received data: {data}")
        except zmq.ZMQError as e:
            print(f"ZMQ Error: {e}")
        except json.JSONDecodeError as e:
            print(f"JSON Decode Error: {e}")

def run_server_in_thread():
    server_thread = threading.Thread(target=receive_data)
    server_thread.daemon = True
    server_thread.start()
    print("ZMQ subscriber thread started")

def update_animation(frame):
    data = data_manager.get_data()

    alpha = data.get('alpha', 0)
    theta = data.get('theta', 0)
    avg_envelope_data = data.get('audio', 0)

    # Set the frame in Blender
    bpy.context.scene.frame_set(frame)

    # Alpha to Hue
    modHue = colourRange(alpha, 1000, 2000)
    hueNode.inputs[0].default_value = modHue
    hueNode.inputs[0].keyframe_insert(data_path='default_value', frame=frame)

    # Audio to Brightness
    modBright = brightRange(avg_envelope_data, 0, 100)
    brightNode.inputs[1].default_value = modBright
    brightNode.inputs[1].keyframe_insert(data_path='default_value', frame=frame)

    # Theta to wiggle
    modWiggle = wiggleRange(theta, 3000, 10000)
    wiggleNode.inputs[1].default_value = modWiggle
    wiggleNode.inputs[1].keyframe_insert(data_path='default_value', frame=frame)

    print(f"Animation updated for frame {frame}")

def frame_change_handler(scene):
    # Update animation for the current frame
    current_frame = scene.frame_current
    update_animation(current_frame)
    
    # Update Blender's UI
    bpy.ops.wm.redraw_timer(type='DRAW_WIN_SWAP', iterations=1)

def main():
    # Start the ZMQ subscriber in a thread to keep Blender responsive
    run_server_in_thread()
    
    # Clear existing frame change handlers to avoid duplicates
    bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre.clear()
    
    # Register the frame change handler
    bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre.append(frame_change_handler)

    print("Blender script initialized. Ready to receive data and update animation.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

If anyone knows anything to help fix this, in order to decode the dictionary properly and to then update the relevant nodes, please tell me!
